# PMML model makes different predictions to original model

Tags: python, java, scikit-learn, pmml, sklearn2pmml

I have built an MLPClassifier in SKLearn for an NLP multi-label classification problem which makes use of CountVectorizer. The aim is to then move this into a Java project with PMML, specifically sklearn2pmml:

```
clf = PMMLPipeline ([('tf', CountVectorizer(token_pattern='\S+', max_features = 400)),
                 ('classifier', MLPClassifier(max_iter=300, random_state=1))
                ])

clf.fit(X, Y)

sklearn2pmml(clf, 'test.pmml', with_repr = True)
```

I am encountering an error when importing the PMML model, whether I import to Java or back into Python. Model makes completely different predictions once imported and always classifies as the same label regardless of input as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukIG0.png).

This varies greatly from the original model, so I assume I must have gone wrong somewhere.

Trying to fix this, I found [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73324406/sklearn2pmml-not-giving-the-same-prediction-output-as-sklearn-pickle-after-loadi) relating to a similar issue. One of the suggestions was to use DataFrames for training the model to avoid ambiguity. I currently use Series so I tried this.

I went from this:

```
X = data['tokenized']
Y = data['Type']
```

To this:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['tokenized'], data = data.get('tokenized'))
Y = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Type'], data = data.get('Type'))
```

However, trying to now train the model I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 8492]
```

Is there a way to use DataFrames without causing an error like this? I've seen other posts suggesting its a difference in size between X and Y, but they both return the same value for .shape.

I'd like to know where I've gone wrong in training my original model, or if its to do with the data format I am passing the exported model. I appreciate any help!

EDIT:

Below is the PMML4S Java implementation which produced the incorrect results:

```
Model model = Model.fromFile(MLModel.class.getClassLoader().getResource("model-3.pmml").getFile());

        Series result = model
                .predict(Series.fromArray(new Object[] { tokenize("<script>alert(1)</script>") }, model.inputSchema()));
        for (int j = 0; j < model.outputFields().length; j++) {
            System.out.println(model.outputFields()[j].name() + " -- " + result.toArray()[j]);
        }
```

With this output:

```
probability(CMD) -- 2.154421715947742E-30
probability(Dir Traversal) -- 1.0667576496332316E-64
probability(SQLi) -- 5.253589894541598E-30
probability(Template) -- 0.9999999997883969
probability(XSS) -- 2.1160304728185066E-10
probability(XXE) -- 2.4613046473076675E-29
```

Using the JPMML library as suggested below, I get the correct results:

```
Evaluator evaluator = new LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder()
                    .load(new File(MLModel.class.getClassLoader().getResource("model-3.pmml").getFile())).build();

            evaluator.verify();

            Map<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<>();
            arguments.put("tokenized", tokenize("<script>alert(1)</script>"));

            Map<String, ?> results = evaluator.evaluate(arguments);

            System.out.println(results.get("Type"));
```

With this output, correctly predicting the class as XSS:

```
{result=XSS, probability_entries=[CMD=0.02470137516811933, Dir Traversal=1.2112725851331142E-5, SQLi=5.288121150550626E-5, Template=9.421616924467085E-6, XSS=0.9716583665392814, XXE=0.003565842738318025], entityId=2/5}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give more information about your PMML deployment side ("whether I import to Java or back into Python"). Are you using PyPMML perhaps?

What are the results if you switch to [JPMML-Evaluator](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator) (for Java) or [JPMML-Evaluator-Python](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator-python) (for Python) instead? The predictions should come out correct now.

> Trying to fix this, I found this Stack Overflow post relating to a similar issue.

The referenced SO post is about PyPMML's broken column mapping mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added an update with both the PMML4S and JPMML libraries in Java. The JPMML library is producing the same predictions as the initial model. Do you know where I went wrong with the PMML4S implementation?

Comment: The crux of the issue is your `CountVectorizer` transformer - it specifies SkLearn-style "matching" behaviour, not PMML-style "splitting" behaviour. The SkLearn2PMML package supports the former via a JPMML vendor extension. Naturally, the JPMML evaluator knows about  such vendor extensions, whereas the PyPMML does not.

Comment: In other words, the problem with PyPMML is that it doesn't warn the end user about unsupported markup. It performs a partial computation, and serves the half-baked result as the final result. Many such cases.